# Откат изменений в Git

Tags: git, git-branch, git-push

В `git` был сделан `push` коммита.

Как его откатить и локально и с сервера?

Answer (score 4):

Комит надо ревертнуть (сделать обратные изменения) командой [**git revert**.](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert)

Откатывать (то есть фактически удалять) коммит, отправленный на удаленный репозиторий, идеологически неверно, потому что кто-то этот коммит может забрать, работать с ним, и быть не в восторге от того что он внезапно исчезнет.

Но если проблема не в том, что вы залили косячный код, а в том что вы опрометчиво храните в репо скажем какие-то пароли, и теперь вывалили их на гитхаб, можно сбросить коммит при помощи

```
git reset --hard
```

и отправить на удаленный репо принудительно примерно так

```
git push -f origin master
```

Но это на крайний случай.

Comment: Нужно удалить push последнего коммита с сервера! С ним работал только я, и изменения которые ушли на сервер с последним коммитом локально и пушем на сервер, полностью неправильные. Тоесть нужно удалить коммит с сервера и локально.